# Why do some ctypes callbacks occur on the main python thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, ctypes

I have a python client with ctypes wrappers to call in to a DLL that in turn talks to a server process. One of the features is to register a callback on an event. I am able to successfully register callbacks, and they do get called on events...so all is working well there.

However, it seems the callbacks are always executed in the "main" thread -- as determined by **threading.currentThread()** -- even when I know there are other commands running in the main thread.

I'm not entirely sure how this happens/or is possible.  The main thread is running a loop, but the callback also reports being in the main thread. Is this something ctypes has control over that I can tweak?

The end game:  I need it to be in a different thread so that any CTRL-C will *not* end up in that thread, and will instead impact the main thread...er, well, what I am thinking of as the main thread (not the callback).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?  It would help to see the code!  Which thread registers the callback?  Is the registration call sync or async?  Which thread is running the code which fires the callback?

Comment: The main thread registers the callback, then goes on to do a while loop. Even though the callback appears to get called asynchronously, I believe that the callback is happening more like an interrupt or signal instead of a a spawned thread. Once I figure out a recipe, I will post it, but my latest plan is to use signal handlers and examine the stack trace to figure out 'where' i am.